# The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later | Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

My drupal site was working fine and i tried to install the "Display Suite" plugin and then i got this error. Please help me fix it.

Below is the error log i got from backend.

```
[19-Apr-2018 13:31:57 Asia/Colombo] Error: Cannot use object of type Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutDefinition as array in /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/modules/layout_plugin/src/Plugin/Layout/LayoutPluginManager.php on line 162 #0 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/modules/layout_plugin/layout_plugin.module(32): Drupal\layout_plugin\Plugin\Layout\LayoutPluginManager->getThemeImplementations()
#1 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(446): layout_plugin_theme(Array, 'module', 'layout_plugin', 'modules/layout_...')
#2 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(333): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'layout_plugin', 'module', 'layout_plugin', 'modules/layout_...')
#3 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(232): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build()
#4 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Utility/ThemeRegistry.php(86): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get()
#5 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Utility/ThemeRegistry.php(67): Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry()
#6 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Registry.php(252): Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:...', Object(Drupal\Core\Cache\DatabaseBackend), Object(Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Lock\DatabaseLockBackend), Array, true)
#7 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php(142): Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime()
#8 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(437): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array)
#9 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#10 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(147): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array)
#11 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(576): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}()
#12 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/HtmlRenderer.php(148): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#13 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/MainContentViewSubscriber.php(90): Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch))
#14 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(108): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent), 'kernel.view', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#15 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(158): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent))
#16 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2)
#17 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#18 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#19 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#20 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#21 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#22 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#23 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2, true)
#24 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber.php(165): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 2)
#25 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber.php(111): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber->makeSubrequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), '/system/403', 403)
#26 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/HttpExceptionSubscriberBase.php(109): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\DefaultExceptionHtmlSubscriber->on403(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))
#27 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(108): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HttpExceptionSubscriberBase->onException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#28 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(230): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))
#29 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(79): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#30 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#31 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#32 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(182): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#33 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(121): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#34 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(75): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#35 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#36 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#37 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#38 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#39 /home/wwwmoh1/public_html/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yet ? Examples ? Code ? Basically enough material to work with so we can maybe identify your problem ? If even you with all the code and this error can't figure out what caused it, are we supposed to do so with only the error message ?

Comment: I try to avoid Display Suite whenever possible. Do you have database access? PHPMyAdmin or something? Console access? Drush? Please update your question. And also please tell us what have you tried so far to fix this issue yourself?